# How to make a Future<int> become a regular int that is usable by arrays?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to keep a shared preferences counter to keep track of an array across my application. The error I running into is that I am returning the value of a Future and trying to use that to define an array index.

Here is the code:

```
var titles = [];

  Future<int> getCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int currentCount = prefs.getInt('counter');
    print('Current Count: $currentCount');
    return currentCount;
  }

  getValue() async {
    final value = await getCounter();
    return value;
  }

  Widget _displayPage()
  {
    int index = getValue();

    titles[index] = 'text';
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 1,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        assert(context != null);
        return new ListTile(
          title: Text('Temp Text'),
          onTap: () async {
            //getCounter();
          }
        );
      }
      );
  }
```

When I try building this page, the exact error I get is: "Type Future is not a sub type of int"

Things I have tried: 
1. Like the code above, I have tried making multiple functions to change it into a regular int
2. I have tried using the return value of getCounter() directly in the definition of the array index like so:

```
titles[getCounter()] = 'text
```

Comment: It's an async method so you need it to run and wait for it to return. Check out example here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are not using a `FutureBuilder`.
Try using a `FutureBuilder`. 
You can solve it by replacing your `displayPage()` widget with the code below.
Check the code below: It works perfectly fine.

```
 Widget _displayPage()
  {
    // use a future builder
    return FutureBuilder<int>(
      // assign a function to it (your getCounter method)
      future: getCounter(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          // print your integer value
          print(snapshot.data);
          return new ListTile(
              title: Text('Temp Text'),
              onTap: () {
              }
          );
        } else {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        }
    );
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be progressing in the right direction. Except now I get "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
The relevant error-causing widget was
    FutureBuilder<int> " as an error. This is after trying to use Text(titles[snapshot.data]) to display a certain index (in this case 0) of the array

Comment: Nevermind, it had to do with how I was creating the  array. I figured it out. Thank you for the help!